# Difference between Step validation and Cross validation

Tags: modeling, cross-validation, predictive-models, validation

I'm trying to model some chemical data from a series of spectra.  I've gone through the preprocessing step and selected "autoscale" (I'm using Pirouette).  And when it comes to validation I'm a little confused as to which one (step or cross) will yield a model that has a good predictive capability.  Any insight would be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure it's "stepwise validation"? It sounds like your software is doing model selection using either a stepwise procedure or using cross-validated accuracy. In which case, this could result in different models, but your question isn't really answerable. (In my limited knowledge, anyhow.)

Answer (score 1):

Validation is the method used to measure the predictive capability, it doesn't change the predictive capability itself. I'm not familiar with the step validation method, but I'm going to assume that it's like cross validation in that it trains the model on a portion of the data, and tests on the rest (possibly doing this multiple times with the data divided different ways). When the model is used "in the field", you'd want to train it on all the available training data to maximize the predictive performance, the validation is just a way of estimating how good the predictions generated in the field will be.

So which one should you use to get the best estimate? Well that depends on what your data represents, how it was collected, etc. I'd need to know more about this step validation (I couldn't find anything with a few google searches), but cross validation is pretty generally useful, so it's hard to go wrong with that.